# What is this plant found in the UK with green and white leaves with purple flowers?

Tags: identification, invasive

Any ideas what this plant is and how to control it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "[Mancuniensis" answer looks good](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/identify-plant-found-in-the-uk-with-green-and-white-leaves-with-purple-flowers/1448#1448), but could you please post a photo, showing a close up of the leaves & flowers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like a variety of the attractive but invasive ground-cover Deadnettle, (Lamium *maculatum*), - see photo [RHS - Lamium maculatum](http://apps.rhs.org.uk/plantselector/plant?plantid=1109) and [here](http://www.7wells.co.uk/dead-nettle---variegated-372-p.asp).

Deadnettle can be difficult to control. Roundup is fairly effective, but you will need to persevere - and also do a bit of hand-weeding - as the plant is tenacious and tends to reappear.

Comment: Yep, I've got a load of this in my garden too, going rampant and strangling one of my hebes. Can't bring myself to tear it all out, mind, as the bees love it. :)